# Why provider is not injecting a simple service on my component?

Tags: angular

I have a simple module that i create:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    PhoneValidationComponent,
    PhoneVerificationComponent,
    PhoneCodeConfirmationComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SharedModule,
  ],
  exports:[
    PhoneValidationComponent
  ],
  providers:[
    PhoneValidationController
  ]
})
```

Simple right? When i see this documentation from angular it says:

https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection

"At the NgModule level, using the providers field of the @NgModule decorator. In this scenario, the HeroService is available to all components, directives and pipes declared in this NgModule. For example:"

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [HeroListComponent]
  providers: [HeroService]
})
class HeroListModule {}
```

But the behavior is not correct, when i go to the page that as the exported component **PhoneValidationComponent**, i get the famous exception:

```
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[PhoneValidationController -> PhoneValidationController -> PhoneValidationController]:
```

But when i put this service on component level it works:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-phone-validation',
  templateUrl: './phone-validation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./phone-validation.component.scss'],
  animations: [
    trigger('visibilityChanged', [
      state('shown', style({ opacity: 1 })),
      state('hidden', style({ opacity: 0 })),
      transition('shown => hidden', animate('600ms')),
      transition('hidden => shown', animate('300ms')),
    ])
  ],
  providers:[
    PhoneValidationController
  ]
})
```

This is the html from the component:

```
<div [@visibilityChanged]="session == 'phone-verification' ? 'shown' : 'hidden'" [ngStyle]="{display: session == 'phone-verification' ? 'block' : 'none'}">
  <app-phone-verification *ngIf="session == 'phone-verification'" (emitBack)="goBack($event)" (emitChangeSession)="changeSession($event)"></app-phone-verification>
</div>

<div [@visibilityChanged]="session == 'phone-code-confirmation' ? 'shown' : 'hidden'" [ngStyle]="{display: session == 'phone-code-confirmation' ? 'block' : 'none'}">
  <app-phone-code-confirmation *ngIf="session == 'phone-code-confirmation'" (emitBack)="goBack($event)" (emitChangeSession)="changeSession($event)"></app-phone-code-confirmation>
</div>
```

My service:

```
@Injectable()
export class PhoneValidationController {

  private user: UserRequest = null as any;
  private phone: string = null as any;

  constructor() {}

  get currentUser(): UserRequest {
    return this.user;
  }

  set currentUser(user: UserRequest) {
    this.user = user;
  }

  get currentPhone(): string {
    return this.phone;
  }

  set currentPhone(phone: string) {
    this.phone = phone;
  }

}
```

I can follow this approach on Component level with no problem, but i want to know why i getting this error if i make the Module approach?

Comment: Your missing the most important info here, what does the service look like and how are you using it?

Comment: @MikeOne i will update my answer but it is a simple object that i want available on this three components from my Module. I will update my question showing the service.

Comment: I think all you need to do is add the `providedIn: 'root'` value to your @Injectable decorator on the service in order to use it in the module. https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#providing-dependency

Comment: You export the `PhoneValidationComponent` to use it in another module? Did you try to add the service to the providers of that other module as well?

Comment: @W.S. yes and i still get the error.

Comment: It's been a while since I worked on an Angular project. How do you import your PhoneModule (or how you called it?) into the other module(s) (AppModule?)? Try to use `{  ngModule: PhoneModule, providers: [PhoneValidationController]  }` within the imports array of your other module. And remove `PhoneValidationController` from the providers in your `PhoneModule`.

Comment: Is there anymore to that NullInjector error message? Can you check if your PhoneValidatorController service been imported successfully into app.module? I have recently experienced this. Does the intellisense provide suggestions to the path of your service file?